# gganimate : more frames with new api?

Tags: r, gganimate

My animation doesn't work anymore when x value goes beyond 100. How does increase the number of frames displayed? The function animate() doesn't work anymore with the new api of gganimate (I use the version 1.0.7)

```
time = seq(1,120)
length(time)
data <- data.frame(
   time, 
   data1 = runif(120, min = 0, max = 25),
   data2 = runif(120, min = 0, max = 25),
   data3 = runif(120, min = 0, max = 25))


p <- ggplot(data) +
      geom_line(aes(time, data1, color= "data1"), size=1) +
      geom_line(aes(time, data2, color = "data2"), size=1) +
      
      view_zoom_manual(
            0, 1, pause_first = FALSE, ease = 'linear', wrap = FALSE,
            xmin = 1:110, xmax = 11:120, ymin = 0, ymax = 25) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 120, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default of `nframes` (which is 100) to the number of frames you need. Try:

```r
animate(p, nframes=120)
```